# Distinct or Groupby in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EntityFramework to build this query:

```
 var result = (from b in _dBContext.AA_V_LOC_BeaconXLocalization
                  where b.IdFloor == floorId && b.data >= dateStart && b.data <= dateEnd
                  orderby b.data descending
                  select new DashBoardBeaconDetailViewModels()
                  {
                      XAxis = b.X_Axis.ToString(),
                      YAxis = b.Y_Axis.ToString(),
                      usertype = b.userType + "",
                      userid = b.idUser + "",
                      Username = b.username,
                      CreatedDate = b.data
                  });
```

I want to group by the result by `idUser` column only. What can I do?

Comment: have you tried this : ``result.GroupBy(u=>u.userid)``?

Comment: I inserted your code, but the result is another object with KEY field. What can I cycle it?

Comment: yeah, this gives you ``IEnumerable<Igrouping<string, DashBoardBeaconDetailViewModels>>`` you can use ``Select`` or ``ToDictionary``. in your question i don't see the expected result :)

Comment: @bircastri this is exactly what `GroupBy` does. What do want to with this grouped data? What is your expected result.?